# Difficulties with running the B2C Accelerator Web Front Ends

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have another problem:

**1 I have configured and initialised the B2C Accelerator**

**2.  I am running the B2C Accelerator, and I can run:**

The MCC;

The PCM;

The hMC;

The WCMS;

The CS Cockpit;

The Admin Cockpit;

The Report Cockpit;

The Admin Console.

**3. I cannot run however, the web store front-ends for:**

Apparel Site DE : http://apparel-de.local:9001/yacceleratorstorefront/

Apparel Site UK : 
http://apparel-uk.local:9001/yacceleratorstorefront/

Electronics Site : 
http://electronics.local:9001/yacceleratorstorefront/

For each Google Chrome returns:

“This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT”

**4. Chcking my hosts file:**

```
##
# BEGIN section for OpenVPN Client SSL sites
127.94.0.1  client.openvpn.net
127.94.0.2  openvpn-client.vpn.contiigo.net
# END section for OpenVPN Client SSL sites

# This is the DNS for apparel-de.local
127.0.0.2   apparel-de.local
127.0.0.3   apparel-uk.local
127.0.0.4   electronics.local
```

**5. Checking my /hybris/config/localextensions.xml file…***

```
    <hybrisconfig xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='../bin/platform/resources/schemas/extensions.xsd'>
      <extensions>
        <path dir='${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}' autoload='false' />
        <extension name='mcc' />
        <extension name='backoffice' />
        <extension name='commercesearchbackoffice' />
        <extension name='commerceservicesbackoffice' />
        <extension name='solrfacetsearchbackoffice' />
        <extension name='solrserver' />
        <extension name='yacceleratorcockpits' />
        <extension name='yacceleratorinitialdata' />
        <extension name='yacceleratorfulfilmentprocess' />
        <extension name='yacceleratorstorefront' />
        <extension name='yaddon' />
        <extension name='ycommercewebservices' />
        <extension name='electronicsstore' />
        <extension name='apparelstore' />
        <extension name='liveeditaddon' />
        <extension name='acceleratorwebservicesaddon' />
      </extensions>
    </hybrisconfig>
```

**6.Clearly there is a mis-configuration: what do I need to do configure the web store front-ends correctly?**

Comment: 127.0.0.2 do you actually think this is valid?

Comment: he said to standby lol

Comment: I hope you would have found your answer by now. I have used 127.0.0.1   apparel-de.local in th host file. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your host file all your local "sub domains" should point to the local network device 127.0.0.1 ..

I have it e.g. something like this:

```
127.0.0.1 b2ctelco.local financialservices.local apparel-uk.local apparel-de.local electronics.local
```

Another approach (the so called `site parameter` approach, see e.g. https://wiki.hybris.com/display/pmtelco/Using+Modulegen+to+Create+a+B2C+Telco+Setup#UsingModulegentoCreateaB2CTelcoSetup-AccessingtheStorefront ) would be to have the explicit `?site=electronics` parameter at the first request to a storefront present.
This is only needed for the first request of a session (to set the BaseSite into the hybris session).

E.g.:

```
http://localhost:9001/yacceleratorstorefront?site=electronics
```

That should work for you now already without any hosts file modifications.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is always used for localhost

change all .2 .3 .4 to .1 in DNS naming system as above mentioned post.

didn't understand why u write .2 .3 .4 for DNS system